# Shopify API gem can't find order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

I'm trying to build an integration with Shopify. Currently I'm trying to retrieve an orders JSON by searching for it's ID. However, every time I get a 404 returned (Resource not found). If I look for it in my browser, I'm able to find it (https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/orders/2507970694.json)

The code that I'm using in my controller is this:

```
def shopify_connection(store, shopify_id)
  shop_url = "https://#{store[:api_key]}:#{store[:password]}@#{store[:store_url]}.myshopify.com/admin"
  logger.debug "=============================store_url: #{shop_url}"
  logger.debug "=============================looking for shopify order id: #{shopify_id}"
  ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
  order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(shopify_id)
  logger.debug "=============================shopify order: #{order.inspect}"
  return order
end
```

Store is the record of the store that I keep in my database (I currently have 3 stores connected to my webapp). When I look at the debugger, the store_url looks alright (compared it to the link that is shown in the Shopify admin site). But it throws an error after the line

```
order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(shopify_id)
```

The next debugger line doesn't show up in the console.
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try this? `orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.where(:ids => '[shopify_id]')`

Comment: what is the error here? You statement should work normally!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and still search for an answer.
What may happen here is that while switching between the shops, that sit on your app, you do not destroy the api_session from one shop and try to access an order from another shop.

Comment: try to send the request using postman , if its working then you need to review the code i'm not ruby developer but we used the filtration by ids and its worked fine in previous projects.

also if you are creating custom app then you need to request token then pass token in header.